# Wrap a synchronous method in Asynchronous call c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous, synchronous

I am looking to wrap synchronous methods into asynchronous code in order to expose those methods as asynchronous - the reason is I do not want to duplicate the code inside the synchrnous methods as I would like it to be DRY and already knowing the functionality of the syunchronous code works - no need to manage separate method as well. However I would like asynchronous methods. I understand the purpose of asynchronous methods at least what they do and why I would want to use them.

Consider the following code:

```
public int AddValues(int a, int b)
{
  // some really boring or extremely long DRY method code 
  return a + b;
}
```

Adding an Asynchronous Calling Method like below
saves time writing code ; Ensures the functionality of the inner code is the same as Synchronous code.
**Could I or Should I do this?:**

```
public async task AddValuesAsync(int a, int b)
{
  return await Task.FromResult(AddValues(a,b));
}
```

And here is my other question and maybe an answer to me; 
Calling the Asynch method twice will also call the sync method - and since it is behind the async I can get a cross thread exception ? IS that correct.

So what should I do in this situation - how to keep it DRY and keep it simple? 
I could make the sync method private and force all calls to the method be Async ..

If you say my example code is a bad way to do it, please give a short reason why and a simple example of a good way to do it ..and any suggestions on what is best and how to do this ?

I have looked here 
[Is wrapping a synchronous call in a Task.Run() to make it asynchronous beneficial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071833/is-wrapping-a-synchronous-call-in-a-task-run-to-make-it-asynchronous-beneficia)
but that does not seem to answer very clearly , what I would like to know.

**EDIT**

For others who are looking - aside from the answer marked here is info that points to the answer with examples and also more importantly why.

[Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

[Which way is best for wrapping synchronous code into an asynchronous method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907427/what-is-the-best-way-for-wrapping-synchronous-code-into-asynchronous-method?rq=1)

Comment: Just my two cents: in web hosting the pool thread that handles the requisition is a limited resource so the async allow you to run your code (the sync AddValues) in a normal thread and once it's complete other pool thread will handle the end of the requisition. The advantage is that your limited pool threads are free to other requests. You could take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx.

Comment: @Max Bundchen - I am not running in web hosting environment. 
please see my edit.

Comment: "if Async method is called anytime the sync method is called I get an oopse (object oriented programming stupid error)."  what does this mean?

Comment: What is the exact error? Don't waste peoples time with nonsense like "oopse".

Comment: Why not use it synchronously when you call it, and let the caller decide if they need to make it async themselves? There's no reason to make it async just because you're calling it from async methods, if that's what you're thinking. You probably need to give real context to make the question answerable.

Comment: @ 31eee384  your answer actually tells me that it is ok to do this; just better to let the caller of the class do it and not put a method in the class  to do the Asynchronous stuff. Is that correct.

Comment: @1.618 it means a stupid me error - for coding it incorrectly; I do not want to get any cross thread exceptions, race conditions or otherwise, so if I am not following the right pattern - I am the guy someone else will say - who is the ID10T. that coded this .

Answer (score 4):

> I am asking this because I would like to know what the proper way is to make a synchronous methods to have asynchronous versions in a class and as DRY as possible.

The proper way is ["don't"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

More to the point, *your API's shouldn't lie*. If they're doing synchronous work, they should have a synchronous signature.

Comment: ok so how would you do this, @Stephen Cleary would you just create the Async Method only, create both methods or as 31eee384 said leave the methods synchronous and let the caller make the async method call ?

Comment: After coming backto this page @Stephen Cleary - a link was showing in the right for related.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907427/what-is-the-best-way-for-wrapping-synchronous-code-into-asynchronous-method?rq=1 - yesterday I could not find anything for what I was trying to do. The link is what I needed to know. Your answer is what I also needed to hear. Direct and to the point!

Comment: @Stix: If your method is just synchronous code, then it should only have a synchronous API, not an asynchronous one.

Answer (score 0):

After comments by Stephen Cleary I found a link on related.. [What is the best way for wrapping synchronous code into asynchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907427/what-is-the-best-way-for-wrapping-synchronous-code-into-asynchronous-method?rq=1)

While not worded exactly - one comment included an article link that was worded exactly to one point of my question.

The comment there by Yuval Itzchakov included this.
"There is great article called [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) by Stephan Toub which talks about all the reasons not to do what you're trying to do. I suggest reading it."