# How to implement truly async methods?

Tags: c#, async-await

I wanted to create a class library with a really sync method, so I wanted to avoid to implement a fake async method that just uses Task.Run to run the sync code.

I have seen that one way is in this way:

```
public Task miMethodAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> miTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new Timer(_ =>
        {
            for (Int64 i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                //todo my long code
            }
            miTcs.SetResult(true);
        })
        .Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);

    return miTcs.Task;
}
```

This solution use a timer to return the task, then in 0ms later, it will run the code inside the timer.

This solution doesn't create a new task so it doesn't take a thread form thread pool, so for scalability is good. But I think that this solution, using the timer to run the sync code, it is not an elegant solution, so I'm wondering how really I could implement a really async method.

Because this solution also I could have my sync method and just implement the asyn method in this way:

```
public Task myMethodAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> miTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new Timer(_ =>
        {
            myMethodSync();
            miTcs.SetResult(true);
        })
        .Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);

    return miTcs.Task;
}
```

But as I comment, I think it is not an elegant solution, but really it seems that is not a fake async method like when I run sync code inside a Task.Run() method.

Comment: If the timer code runs in the same thread (and this one is the UI-thread) and is long-running it will still freeze the UI. If; however, the timer creates a new thread, what are you winning by hiding this with a timer?

Comment: This is going to use up a thread for as long as the synchronous method is running.  Whether that's the active thread, UI thread, or threadpool thread, depends on which of the half-dozen classes named `Timer` in the .NET library you are using, along with which thread calls `myMethodAsync()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you would want to make an `async` wrapper over synchronous code? Assuming you read the cited post [from your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845005/is-it-really-a-bad-idea-to-use-threads-in-a-class-library) you know that it's a bad idea. Are you fulfilling a `Task` returning interface? If so, return either `Task.FromResult` or `Task.CompletedTask` and again let the client decide when to offload the process. Without more details all you'll get is recitations of previous advice, i.e. [**don't do it**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642687/7339946).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These wrappers that just wrap synchronous code into a pseudo `async` method are good for nothing. The recommended way is not to create any such wrappers but rather let the API users do Task.Run(SyncMethod) themselves.

Check out this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) for the details.